# I'm trying to save mesh but nothing is saving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load, mesh

I am new in unity.

I am trying to save mesh with `SerializableDictionary`. When I try to save the game there are no errors, but the values in the save files are empty.

Someone suggested that I need to call the `UpdateGeometryWithMoreVertices` method for it to save but I don't know how to use it.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or if I'm saving the right thing
The code is in the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ntMDsmvd).

Comment: What a mess.
you have to make it easier for people to help you, there's a few versions of the code commented and two scripts all in one. you should put some effort on your question. share the relevant parts here with code blocks, and maybe a link to each complete class on paste bin if relevant. please read the section [Sample code and data](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I have a destructible terrain. The terrain is made from blocks. Each block have a mesh. I am trying to save and load the shape of the mesh, but I don't know if I am doing it right. Sorry for bad explanation of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy but I tried to make sense of it.

Here in [GameData](https://pastebin.com/dQm24SXA) you didn't have this package:

`using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;`

Or other that implements `SerializableDictionary<>` least wasn't referenced on the file you shared.

And in [DestructibleBlock](https://pastebin.com/84cLUybq) there are a few Classes that aren't Referenced.

I fixed a few syntax errors and pointed to some odd attempts to pass wrong types or call *ghost* methods.

I believe some might be due to lack of access to the rest of your project but this seems overcomplicated for the level of understanding that I am assuming you have.

If the edits on [GameData](https://pastebin.com/dQm24SXA) and [DestructibleBlock](https://pastebin.com/84cLUybq) dont put you in the right direction you should reformulate your question, explaining your code section by section.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation of the problem. I am bad at english so I could not explain it very well. The code is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EygJSTL-B-k I sent only the code I edited. If needed I can try to send the rest of the code but I don't know if I can explain it very well.

Comment: without saving, is it working?

Comment: Yes, It works I can destroy terrain(change the shape of the mesh) there are no errors, but nothing is saving.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using this save and load system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUi9aijvpgs